# SSO keycloak with winform

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, keycloak

I am doing a POC for keycloak SSO and was able to connect web apps to keycloak ,
now I am trying to have the same thing with WinForms.
I want it to be able to login from KC from a WinForms app , and if the user already logged-in in the web it will sign in automatically , is it possible to do that, and if you can guide me to git repository that already have that implemented it would be great .
I search for any WinForms that authenticate with keycloak and was unable to find.